# Do I need use messagePack serialization over JSON if my client and server already supported per message deflate compression?

Tags: go, networking, websocket, http-compression, permessagedeflate

My client and server are communicating through WebSocket with the JSON serialized data and both are supporting per message deflate and I suppose the JSON data is already compressed.
The server is written on go and using gorrilla's WebSocket package.
My goal is to decrease more traffic so wondering if I change the JSON serialization to MessagePack and continue to use per-message deflate header would it help to decrease the traffic ?

Comment: Encode some sample messages as JSON and MessagePack, compress and compare.

Comment: This depends entirely on the nature and size of your messages and is impossible for us to predict. As Cerise said, measure it.